# TypeError: _reactNative.Animated.Value is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, mobile

I'm running into the above issue when trying to run just unit tests for my react-native module.

For more context I am on `"react-native": "^0.64.1"`.

```
import { Animated } from "react-native";
...
const pan = new Animated.Value(0); // TypeError: _reactNative.Animated.Value is not a constructor
```

When I printed `Animated` in my jest unit test I found that it was an empty object. I also tried printing out `React` and it returned what I expected so this seems like its related to `react-native` specifically.

```
console.log __tests__/SomeAnimator.test.js:63
    Animated {}
```

I realize I could just mock react-native modules but that seems very clunky.

```
jest.mock("react-native", () => {
    return {
        Animated: {
            Value: jest.fn(() => ({
                interpolate: jest.fn(),
                setValue: jest.fn(),
                addListener: jest.fn(),
                stopAnimation: jest.fn(),
                flattenOffset: jest.fn(),
                extractOffset: jest.fn(),
            }))
        },
        Easing: {
            bezier: jest.fn()
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?